# Are Java 8 Streams the same as .Net IEnumerable?

Tags: java, .net, java-8

At first I thought Java Streams were necessarily related to I/O but they look really like the IEnumerable interface in .Net.

Is that comparison fair?

Answer (score 40, accepted):

Maybe this is something interesting I found on google for you:

**Streams**

Java streams (not to be confused with InputStream and OutputStream) do more or less the same thing as LINQ, with parallel processing mirroring PLINQ.  There isn't any nice SQL-like syntax to use, though - you have to do it function-style.  And just as LINQ required extension methods, streams don't appear until Java 8 because they need defender methods to work with existing collection types.

Stream is largely equivalent to .NET IEnumerable.  To see how they're similar, consider these examples:

```
// Write each value in a collection to standard output on a separate line:

// C# - LINQ
myCollection.ForEach( x => Console.WriteLine(x) );
// Java - stream
myCollection.stream().forEach( x -> System.out.println(x) );

// Sum all the values in a (potentially large) collection, using parallelism
// if possible:

// C# - PLINQ
int sum = myCollection.AsParallel().Aggregate( (x, y) => x + y );
// Java - parallel stream
int sum = myCollection.stream().parallel().reduce( (x, y) -> x + y );
```

You would expect the stream() method to be on Iterable, in the same way as LINQ operates on IEnumerable, but it's on Collection instead.  Perhaps it's because Java lacks yield-return semantics, so Iterable is just less interesting or useful in Java.

source: http://leftoblique.net/wp/2013/07/25/java-8-a-k-a-oracle-finally-catches-up-to-net-framework-3-0/

**EDIT:**
There is a lot to find about it on Google. Here are some more interesting articles:
https://web.archive.org/web/20130331002411/http://blog.informatech.cr/2013/03/24/java-streams-preview-vs-net-linq/

Comment: Stream is for a very good reason not iterable. The functional pattern is all about internal iteration. The caller does not need to care how it is done. In C# both concepts are mixed and not very clean. If it would be iterable it would support external iteration just like c# which is not very elegant in terms of functional programming.

Comment: In C# the iteration implementation itself also encapsulated into a blackbox: the implementor of IEnumerator. So if you have a tree which is IEnumerable, the iteration available via the IEnumerable's GetEnumerator() method which returns and IEnumerator. Nothing wrong and mixed here. Java belongs to OOP, not functional, so forcing to be functional is not elegant. Nothing wrong with functional concept btw. Forcing encapsulation, lowering dependencies is  and still opening OOP style choices, that's elegant.